# Unity 3d auto-move player forward script

Tags: unity

Trying to write a basic script to attach to the player on Unity 3D, I want them to move forward automatically. I'm guessing that will be part of the Update function and using transform, but that's about as far as I get.

I'm assuming it's a Transform.translate function too, but not sure what parameters to use to move forward 1 m/s automatically (for example). Also, how do I block W and S keys moving forwards and backwards, and instead use the for up and down? (My character is 'floating' and I'm looking to incorporate space harrier style controls)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sample code is what you want. 
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html

```
function Update() 
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Vector3.forward is the same as (0,0,1), and transform.Translate() is local translate, so Translate(0,0,1) is always moving forward. Time.deltaTime let speed equal to 1 m/s.

And you can change the default key in "Input Manager"
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-InputManager.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a [Character Controller](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) and use either [SimpleMove](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html) or [Move](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html).

Comment: Are there any tutorials, videos etc. that covers this is a little more detail? Just looking at those links has only succeeded in confusing me a little more.

Answer (score 0):

this is C# version

```
public float speed=1f;

void Update() 
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime*speed);
}
```

you will have a field in inspector to change speed when you add the script to a gameobject. :-)